# Store a timestamp with Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus

I would like to make a custom metric to store *datetime.now* in Prometheus metrics, someone know how do it?
I tried to do it with **gauge** but the set predefined function seem to work only with *double*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example with python:

```py
import time
import prometheus_client as prom
g = prom.Gauge("name", "description")
g.set(time.time())
prom.write_to_textfile('metrics.txt', prom.REGISTRY)
```

'metrics.txt' will contain this:

```
# HELP name description
# TYPE name gauge
name 1.6287478272555726e+09
```

The value of the metric and `time.time()` both are epoch time (aka [unixtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), just as Prometheus `time()` function.